# ls: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, command-line, vim, path

I have been messing around trying to install macvim to a higher version of 7.4. I finally got it working but now I get the error

```
ls: No such file or directory
```

when looking for a directory. I can temporarily fix it by using the command

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

however, as soon as I exit my terminal window the problem returns. How do I fix this permanently?

Comment: Look into your  `~/.bashrc` & `~/.profile` files with an editor.

Comment: Cross-posted to SO, and a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234117/ls-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you messed up `/etc/profile`.

Normally PATH is defined in `/etc/profile` and `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @user3063666 whatever it was you did to those files, undo the changes. If you can tell us what you did to them then anyone here can almost certainly tell you how to fix it.